# SXA 1.4 is not rendering JSON correctly

Tags: sxa

I'm using SXA 1.4 on Sitecore 8.2 Update 4 to generate JSON feed, but the JSON feed is not being generated correctly. When I navigate to my URL, I get this JSON feed:

```
{"subject":"Your results","message":"   &lt;div style=&quot;max-width: 900px;&quot; &gt;
   &lt;!--[if mso]&gt;
      &lt;table role=&quot;presentation&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;
      &lt;tr&gt;
      &lt;td width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;
      &lt;![endif]--&gt;



Hello &lt;%${name}%&gt;,
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
Message Information here.
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;strong&gt;I have a link here:&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;https://Some/Website/I/Like/&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Assessment Results&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/a&gt; 
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
More text goes here, because I like to send long emails.
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
Even more text goes here.

&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
This is a really long email with carriage returns and linefeeds!
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
Even more text
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;p style=&quot; padding-top:0; margin-top:0; text-align:center; font-size: 12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#cccccc;&quot;&gt;Source&amp;nbsp;Code:&amp;nbsp; 586703
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;!-- Container part two : BEGIN --&gt;      
   &lt;!--[if mso]&gt;
   &lt;/td&gt;
   &lt;/tr&gt;
   &lt;/table&gt;
   &lt;![endif]--&gt;
   &lt;/div&gt;"}
```

This is all good, except the linefeed and carriage return characters are not valid JSON (according to these pictures taken from https://www.json.org/):

[image: JSON Definition example 1]
[image: JSON Definition example 2]

Is there a setting that I can use to make SXA correctly encode (or remove) the carriage return/line feed characters? Or is this something that only a patch from Sitecore can solve?

Comment: I strongly recommend upgrading to more recent version of an SXA. There were some issues in the past in way how SXA was rendering JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, SXA 1.4 is the last version that is supported on Sitecore 8.2 Update 4. We have plans to upgrade to 8.2 Update 7, but that doesn't help me right now. It's nice to know that SXA has made a lot of good progress since version 1.4. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: But to your point, @DawidRutkowski, SXA 1.7 Update 1 does not have this issue. So it sounds like it's off to Sitecore support for a fix. Thanks!